# Onboarding data in weka showing unusual error

Tags: csv, weka

I was just trying to onboard a CSV format data in weka and I don't know why these weird characters have been added before the 'title' attribute. There have no issues in the CSV format file. Also, when I try to rename the title in the csv file and again try to onboard surprisingly it only fetch the odd attributes. Pretty weird behaviour getting from weka. Do anyone know the reason behind it or it's just a bug?

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your CSV file has a [UTF-8 byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding) at the start. For Java, there shouldn't be a BOM in the file (see [here](https://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-handle-utf8-file-with-bom.html)). In theory, you should be able to just remove it with a text editor.